# Line coordinates

Tags: math, line

how can we calculate the coordinates of a line (Formula used) when the length and angle is given.

I have to make a pop up box which will take as input the length and angle and will draw a line.
just need the formula

Answer (score 2):

Assuming one end of the line is at `(x0, y0)`, the other end will be at:

```
x1 = x0 + r cos(t * pi / 180)
y1 = y0 + r sin(t * pi / 180)
```

where `r` is the length of the line and `t` is the angle in degrees.